# Corel Video Studio 7 will not run

Tags: windows-7

After applying windows updates, Corel Video Studio Pro 7 can't run.

After I installed the updates, it worked.

Is there a quicker way than re-installing updates one-by-one to see which update is causing the problem?

Comment: Could you explain the problem. Why can't Corel Visual Studio Pro 7 run? What happens when you try?

Comment: I see Faulting application vstudio.exe in the eventviewer application log. Then I uninstalled all the recent updates and it works again. It seems that one of the recent update patches causes the conflict, But I can't find out which patch.

Comment: Install the updates one at a time until it stops working. The problem will be the last one you installed.

Comment: Thanks. When I update one at a time, it is needed to reboot to take effect. I just wonder if there is a more efficient way to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2):

#### Corel video studio pro 7 can't run.

> I have to uninstall all the recent updates to make it work.

You need to install the **Corel VideoStudio X7 Hotfix 1** patch. See below for more information.

This fixed a problem with the [February 2016 Windows 7 Security Update](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms16-feb.aspx) (which contained a number of different patches).

---

#### VideoStudio Updates

> Hotfix 1 is now available for VideoStudio X7 in Windows 7.
>
> This update fixes launch issues caused by the February 2016 Windows 7
>   Security Update from Microsoft.

Released: 2016-02-23

Source [VideoStudio Updates](http://www.videostudiopro.com/en/support/updates/#vsp-version-tab=2)